# undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow6StatusC1ENS_5error4CodeESt17basic_string_viewIcSt11char_traitsIcEE

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6

When I try to run the stylegan2 on my linux server, it will report this error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/chengjun/stylegan2-master/dnnlib/tflib/_cudacache/fused_bias_act_7d2d3f0f4df7f9e30ecb88ac743fb7c2.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow6StatusC1ENS_5error4CodeESt17basic_string_viewIcSt11char_traitsIcEE
```

And I find there is no link with _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so and tensorflow_framework.so

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd15788000)
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2a79400000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2a7975e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2a79000000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2a7985f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2a79677000)
```

So I export the lib as the following

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/chengjun/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/
```

And run again, it still reports the same error. However, the I use ldd to check the so file and I find it has linked with the tensorflow.

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd57f6c000)
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so => /home/chengjun/ENTER/envs/python1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so (0x00007fa08c400000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa08c000000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa0c5959000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa08bc00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa0c5a5a000)
    libtensorflow_framework.so.1 => /home/chengjun/ENTER/envs/python1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so.1 (0x00007fa089e00000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa0c5952000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa08c319000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa0c594d000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa0c5948000)
```

Now I don't know how to debug, does anyone know how to solve it?